# Get android phone location over text message

Tags: android, gps

Is there an app that will text back the location of a cell phone over text message for android?

Root is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use [Automate](https://llamalab.com/automate/) application. You can create flow to get current location and send it via SMS.

Unfortunately I do not have first hand experience but the application seems self-explained.

Comment: So auto text every certain number of hours then?

Comment: @William, as far as I understood you can schedule those flows

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SMS my GPS](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.github.warren_bank.sms_automatic_reply_gps). Per the app's description, it should meet your requirements just fine:

> *SMS my GPS* listens for incoming SMS text/data messages and conditionally sends an automatic reply containing GPS location data. The „trigger-word“ and white-listed sender phone number can be configured in the app.

With just 190k APK size it's quite handy. Haven't tried it myself, so I cannot tell how reliable it works – but as it's free and open source, certainly worth giving it a try.